# Is Combinatorial Chemistry related to combinatorics in math?

Tags: terminology

If the answer is no, then I don't understand the adjective "Combinatorial". Barring decompositions, aren't the [five main types](https://akwebclass.blogspot.com/2019/10/chemical-reaction-types.html) of chemical reactions combinatorial? You must combine at least two reactants for a reaction!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Combinatorial chemistry usually refers to changing the choice of A and B, and when the reaction products differ according to the type of reaction, also the type of reaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the term "combinatorial" chemistry is related to mathematical combinatorics. Imagine that we have three positions (numbered 1, 2, 3) on a molecule, and at each position, we can place any one of 5 functional groups (A, B, C, D, E). We can synthesize all possible molecules in parallel by making all possible derivatives at position 1 (5 total), then reacting all of those molecules to make all possible derivatives at position 2 (5 for each of the 5 intermediates) and then again at position 3 (again, 5 new molecules for each product of step 2). In this example, we would produce 5x5x5=125 combinations as our final output.

Comment: In addition to the examples given, e.g., on [Wikipedia's entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_chemistry), combinatorial chemistry is not constrained to small organic and larger biomolecules.  Folks in catalysis screen by means of combinatorial chemistry libraries of e.g., mixed metal oxides, too.